# What does RATTLE OUT mean?

Tags: idioms

And they asked me if I weren't an actor what would I do and I RATTLED OUT I'd be a doctor

Comment: Macmillan defines this picturesque multi-word reporting verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears only  MacMillan Dictionary gives a definition  of the phrasal verb [rattle out](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rattle-out):

> to produce a series of quick loud noises or words
>
> - He rattled out a series of questions.

Probably a variant of [rattle off](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rattle-off).  Note that ***rattle***,  meaning talking fast, has a long history:

> Also, reel off. ***Utter or perform rapidly or effortlessly, often at length.***  For example, The treasurer rattled off the list of all those who had not paid their dues, or She reeled off song after song.
>
> ***The verb rattle has been used for fast talking since the late 1300s and for other kinds of fast production since the late 1800s*** (George Bernard Shaw wrote of “men who rattle off their copy” in a letter of 1896). The verb reel off, which alludes to unwinding from a reel, has been used figuratively since about 1830.

(AHD)